# Convert from physical dimensions to axis cs coordinate values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, lengths

In answering [PGFPlots: How to draw a label at a zero of a function?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169971/pgfplots-howto-draw-a-label-at-a-zero-of-a-function), I got stuck on converting a length in `pt` to the actual coordinate value in the `axis cs` system.

Here I only need the `x` value, but my question is how does one obtain the actual `x`/`y` values of a coordinate once you have their physical location.

#### Sub-Question:

- Why does the circle not get drawn for the intersection on the left once I use `\pgfextra`?

[image]

### Notes:

- Physical coordinate locations can be extracted as per [Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz).

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz
\newdimen\XCoord
\newdimen\YCoord
\newcommand*{\ExtractCoordinate}[1]{\path (#1); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord};}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            domain=-4:7,
            xmax=7,
        ]
        \addplot[no marks,blue,thick, name path global=My Graph] {x*x-4*x-7};
        \addplot[no marks,draw=none,  name path global=x Axis  ] {0};
        \fill[red,name intersections={of=My Graph and x Axis,total=\t}]
            \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{
                \pgfextra{\ExtractCoordinate{intersection-\s}}
                (intersection-\s) circle (2pt) 
                node [above] {$\XCoord$}
            };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should I copy my answer here?

Comment: BTW, you've got a \path inside a \fill (not good).  You would be better off using \whereami (see  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168452/how-can-i-draw-a-3d-three-sided-5-7-9-triangle-with-tikz-or-pstricks/168482#168482).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Originally posted on [PGFPlots: How to draw a label at a zero of a function?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169971/pgfplots-how-to-draw-a-label-at-a-zero-of-a-function/170016#170016)
There may be a better way than this, but I haven't found one yet.

[image: tick marks]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\newlength{\len}
\newlength{\plotwidth}
\newcommand{\getvalue}[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/#1}}

%output will be given by \pgfmathresult
\newcommand{\xcoord}[1]% #1 = node name
{\pgfplotsextra{%
  \pgfextractx{\len}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfplotspointaxisxy{0}{0}}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}}%
  \pgfextractx{\plotwidth}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfplotspointaxisxy{\getvalue{xmin}}{0}}%
    {\pgfplotspointaxisxy{\getvalue{xmax}}{0}}}%
  \pgfmathparse{\len*(\getvalue{xmax}-\getvalue{xmin})/\plotwidth}%
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            domain=-4:7
        ]
        \addplot[no marks,blue,thick, name path global=My Graph] {x*x-4*x-7};
        \addplot[no marks,draw=none, name path global=x Axis] {0};
        \path[name intersections={of=My Graph and x Axis,total=\t}];

        \draw[very thin,color=gray] (intersection-1) -- +(0,-5mm) coordinate(tick1);
        \xcoord{tick1}%
        \node[below] at (tick1) {$\pgfmathresult$};

        \draw[very thin,color=gray] (intersection-2) -- +(0,-5mm) coordinate(tick2);
        \xcoord{tick2}%
        \node[below] at (tick2) {$\pgfmathresult$};
     \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It should be noted than you get the wrong answer if \xcoord is inside a node (text field) or a path, and obviously if any other \pgfmath calculation occurs between it an \pgfmathresult.  Also, \pgfplotsconvertunittocoordinate and \pgfplotsunitxlength were tried unsucessfully.

Comment: This looks good, except for assuming that there are two intersections -- but that wasn't the thrust of this question (so is acceptable). Also, _all_ numbers should be in math mode, otherwise the negative sign is nor properly formatted (so use `$\pgfmathresult$` instead of `\pgfmathresult` in the `\node`.

Comment: @Peter Grill - I tried \foreach without success.  I haven't tried \loop \repeat yet.  The other suggestion has been implemented.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on John's very nice answer, I've copied some definitions from [Plot functions and their point of intersection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88386/plot-functions-and-their-point-of-intersection). It is in turn based on Jake's previous code linked in that question.

Here, one of the main issues is the sample number and number of intersection computations. If you consider the following example, I've commented out the node that displays the number of intersections found which might be helpful to see the problem.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\makeatletter
\def\markxof#1{%
\pgf@process{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
\pgfmathparse{\pgf@x/\pgfplotsunitxlength 
             +\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@SHIFT@x)/
             10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@x
             }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        domain=-4:4,
        after end axis/.code={
          \foreach \x in {1,...,\mytot}{
             \draw[very thin,color=gray] (intersection-\x) -- +(0,-5mm) coordinate(tick\x);
             \node[below] at (tick\x) 
               {\markxof{tick\x}$\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]\pgfmathresult$};
          }
       }
    ]
    \addplot[no marks,blue,thick, name path global=My Graph,smooth] {x^3-8*x+3};
    \addplot[no marks,draw=none, name path global=x Axis] {0};
    \path[name intersections={of=My Graph and x Axis,total=\mytot},
          /utils/exec={\xdef\mytot{\mytot}}]
        %node[right] at (axis cs:1,15) {\mytot\ intersections}
        ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The reason is that if the sample number is high enough the paths that form the general path get too small and trigger false positives for intersection. One option might be drawing once the curve invisibly (`draw=none`) to get the intersections with smooth version and overlay the original path on top as visible. Add remove the `smooth` option below.

Finally, the total count of intersections doesn't survive the path (let alone the axis) since it is probably designed to be used immediately in the same path.

[image]